# Google Sheets SUMIFS does not work

Tags: google-sheets

can't get SUMIFS with dates to work properly.
I have a sheet with amount of daily exercise rep count and a cell on top with weekly average. But the average does not work.
average formula looks like this:

```
=SUMIFS(C7:C100, $A7:$A100, ">(TODAY()-7)", $A7:$A100, "<=TODAY()")
```

Example page: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hfdSWX9bNkR1TeUKO1vnbSXT740D2-64Gi5smX0oB5A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the calls to the `TODAY()` function outside of quotes.

```
=SUMIFS(C7:C100, $A7:$A100, ">"&(TODAY()-7), $A7:$A100, "<="&TODAY())
```

Comment: Excel's criteria parser is not a full evaluation engine, instead being a very limited parser with only basic capabilities. Functions such as `>TODAY()` and expressions such as `>(1+1)` are not handled by the parser, and the `SUMIF` function will return `0` if these are used as criteria.